# How can system logs be enabled in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, logging

I have a MacBook Pro running 10.6.7 and for a while now it hasn't been logging anything to the system logs.  When I look in the Console's All Messages the only logs I see look like this (and it appears once a day):

```
3/23/11 8:48:01 AM kernel        npvhash=4095
```

The system.log file is completely empty.  I checked the /etc/syslog.conf and everything appears fine:

```
*.notice;authpriv,remoteauth,ftp,install,internal.none  /var/log/system.log
kern.*                                                  /var/log/kernel.log

# Send messages normally sent to the console also to the serial port.
# To stop messages from being sent out the serial port, comment out this line.
#*.err;kern.*;auth.notice;authpriv,remoteauth.none;mail.crit            /dev/tty.serial

# The authpriv log file should be restricted access; these
# messages shouldn't go to terminals or publically-readable
# files.
auth.info;authpriv.*;remoteauth.crit                    /var/log/secure.log

lpr.info                                                /var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                                                  /var/log/mail.log
ftp.*                                                   /var/log/ftp.log
install.*                                               /var/log/install.log
install.*                                               @127.0.0.1:32376
local0.*                                                /var/log/appfirewall.log
local1.*                                                /var/log/ipfw.log

*.emerg                                                 *

# Send kernel messages to FIFO for Norton Personal Firewall
kern.*                                                  /var/log/Npfkernel.log.fifo
```

Has anybody ever seen a system that just stops logging and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line might be the problem:

```
# Send kernel messages to FIFO for Norton Personal Firewall
kern.*                                                  /var/log/Npfkernel.log.fifo
```

Since you have kern.* entries being logged to /var/log/kernel.log above, the system chokes, not knowing where to send the kernel notices (does it send it to kernel.log or Npfkernel.log.fifo?).

You will have to pick one or the other to store the kernel notices.